# Create transparent object on canvas to overlay previous object by z-index

Tags: wpf, xaml, canvas, transparency

Creating WPF application with something about augmented reality, there is a trouble.
I have user control with several Z-layers, first of them is live video (simple Image for user control), and second is a Canvas.
I have mapped skeleton joints to draw it and bones on canvas. But I need to draw bones with offsets from joints. Because of technical requirements of task, I need create it without code-behind.
The simplest solution is to draw transparent ellipse mapped to joint position on canvas, which will overlay line for bone representation. The transparency is neseccary because of video.

So, the main question is how to design transparent object on WPF Canvas which will overlay objects on canvas by it's Z-index via XAML?

Comment: `<Ellipse Fill="Transparent" Panel.ZIndex="1000" .../>` - what exactly have you tried?

Comment: @Clemens, thanks for reply. I need ellipse that'll be transparent for background image, but will overlay other objects on canvas.

Answer (score 0):

By setting the attached property `Canvas.ZIndex` controls the layering of objects on a `Canvas`. The default is *0* which is the bottom most layer.
Setting `UIElement.Opacity` to a value between *0* and *1* controls the opacity from transparent to solid:

```
<Canvas>
  <Ellipse Height="50" Width="50" Fill="Blue" 
           Canvas.ZIndex="1" Canvas.Left="25" />
  <Ellipse Height="50" Width="50" Fill="Yellow" />
  <Ellipse Height="50" Width="50" Fill="Red" 
           Canvas.ZIndex="2" Canvas.Left="50" 
           Opacity="0.7" />
</Canvas>
```